# rfid programming

Tags: c#, hardware, delphi

I have 2 readers for RFID and some cards (from a Chinese company called "Daily RFID"). They
kind of work because they came with some demo software written in Delphi that reads the id of the card (myfare compatible, ISO14443A). The problem is that if I try to use the demo to write to them, it doesnt seem to work.

They have another demo written in C#, it compiles and runs, but when click on `Connect`, I get this error:

> Unhanded exception.. unable to load
>   DLL 'BasicB.DLL'

So I put the DLL in %WINDOWS%/system32, but when I tried to run `regsvr32 BasicB.dll`, I got another error:

> the module "BasicB.dll" was loaded but
>   hte entry-point DllRegisterServer was
>   not found. Make sure that "BasicB.dll"
>   is a valid DLL or OCX file and then
>   try again

I have written to the company but got no response.

I program in Objective-C, so I kind of understand c#, but how to make these cards work?

Should I continue with Delphi, and try to write to them with it? Or should I continue trying with C#? Either way, would I have to write the code to read/write to them, or is there any software to work with these modules?

Comment: This is really off topic for Programmers'. As it's a programming question it could be migrated to Stack Overflow, but I don't think it will get answered in it's current form.

Comment: @ChrisF I edited the question. Do you think it can be migrated now? If so, please go ahead. Thanks.

Comment: *it does not seem to work* is not a good description of what's going on... usually you got a error message or a unexpected behavior... what is this?

Are you sure the BasicB.DLL contains a OLE object –for example ActiveX object? If not, you have not to register it to using the regsvr32, just put it there and the system will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only use `regsvr32` to register ActiveX (COM) DLLs. The DLL you're trying to register isn't one.

Putting the DLL in the `%WINDOWS%\system32`folder should be enough. In fact, it can be in your applications folder or anywhere on the PATH.

Comment: wouldn't app directory be less invasive?

Comment: You're right. I should have mentioned the app's directory as well as anywhere on the PATH. Updated. Thanks, @David.

Comment: @David - In my defense, though, the OP did say he'd already put in in System32. :)